# rqt_bag only shows first part of split bagfile

Tags: rosbag, rqt-bag

When opening a ros2-bagfile, that consists of multiple part (recorded with `--max-bag-duration` option), rqt_bag only shows the messages from the first part. Eventhough the time-axis is scaled to the full bagfile duration.If I merge all my bagfile parts using `ros2 bag convert`, the all messages over the full duration are shown.

Any ideas why this happens? Anyone else having the same problem?
[image]

Comment: Please edit your post to tell us which version of ros2 you are using. For playback, have you tried giving a directory name instead of a bagfile name?